# How to get precise performance measurements on desktop client-server application

Tags: performance-testing, metrics, hp-uft

as part of our quality metrics we need to calculate the time the application under test (a windows client - server desktop application) takes to execute some common tasks like time to open a window, time to save a document, etc.

The common use cases include the maximum time allowed to complete the use case in a specified machine and we need to validate these times every sprint.

We use UFT (HP Unified Functional Testing (UFT)) as our testing tool but the times we get on a sample application have big variations. We have disabled everything on the computer, the CPU is near 0% and we have variations of 15% on the measures we do.

Have you experience gathering this kind of metrics in projects? What tool did you use or how did you got the information? Doing it manually is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

QTP provides a timing mechanism in it's MercuryTimers object... It's a collection of named timers that you can start, stop, continue, reset, and read it's elapsed time.  Because it's a collection, you can set several simultaneous timers and read them independently of each other.

You don't need to declare or dimension them at all, they come into existence as soon as you call a method on them.  They also persist across actions, and because they use literal strings for names, you can parameterize the names in any way you choose.

Here's an example:

```
MercuryTimers("App Life Time").Start
MercuryTimers("Load Time").Start

systemUtil.Run TestURL

if not Browser("IE").Exist(60) then
   FailTestBecause "Browser load timeout"
End If

MercuryTimers("Load Time").Stop

TimeTakenToLoad = MercuryTimers("Load Time").ElapsedTime

RunAction "Do Other Stuff"

RunAction "Exit and Close Browser"

MercuryTimers("App Life Time").Stop

TotalTimeAppExisted = MercuryTimers("App Life Time").ElapsedTime

SomeOutputFunction "Load Time:" & TimeTakenToLoad & " - Exist Time:" & TotalTimeAppExisted & " - in milliseconds"
```

As far as eliminating all unnecessary processes on the test machine, It sounds like you already did that.  I always check blackviper.com for windows services information.

Comment: We did that and we get variations over the same code of 15% on a sample app that only has a button with a sleep inside ... :S

Comment: Any chance the disk drive of the test machine is doing some work while the timer is running?  Drive access can cause random variations in overall performance of any given test machine.  You could check the disk with tools like SpinRite (or if you're REALLY technical, look up "MHDD" by Dmitry Postrigan)...  Also, if you haven't already done so, look up BlackViper.Com for services configuration samples that could further stabilize the platform.